# Which scripture mention about sexual relationships in heavenly lokas?

Tags: puranas, lokas, swarga

According to some quora answer-

> The phenomenon of urdhwa reta When one reaches to this state, Vital
> energy has enormous potential energy. It rises up like steam does and
> reaches his ajna chakra or the point between his eyebrows. This is
> called ojas state. [ojas = radiant life energy] . The sperms in such
> people flow upwards till Agya-Chakra and then are directed towards the
> female ovary.
>
> The phenomenon of Manas-praveti These people from
> Sidha-loka and in the higher realm don’t need physical sex to beget a
> child. They can do it by the strength of mind

Which scripture mention about above things?

Comment: Ojas is subtle component of Veerya. Never heard of such Union. But i think it is Ojas which moves towards Ajna Chakra.